# Linear programing, objective function. variable depending on the sign of another variable

Tags: linear-programming

I have the variable Si. How to express a variable Di in LP that satisfies:

- `Di=100*Si` if `Si>=0`
- `Di=-200*Si` if `Si<0`

The objective function would be `Min{Sum(Di)}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's cleaner to define two variables that represent the positive and negative parts of `Si`. Call them `Si1` (= positive part) and `Si2` (= negative part).

```
Si1 - Si2 = Si
Si1, Si2 >= 0
```

---

Probably you will also need constraints that say that if `Si < 0` then `Si1` *must* equal 0, and if `Si > 0` then `Si2` *must* equal 0. Introduce an additional binary variable `y` that equals 1 if `Si > 0`, equals 0 if `Si < 0`, and could equal either if `Si = 0`:

```
-M * (1 - y) <= Si
 M * y >= Si
```

where `M` is a large constant.
Then require `Si1 = 0` if `y = 0` and `Si2 = 0` if `y = 1`:

```
Si1 <= M * y
Si2 <= M * (1 - y)
```

Then set your objective function to `minimize 100 * Si1 + 200 * Si2`.

---

**Note:** If both `Si1` and `Si2` have positive coefficients in the objective function, and the objective is a minimization, then you do *not* need the stuff after the divider line. The two constraints before the line are sufficient, because we will always want to set `Si1` and `Si2` as small as possible, which means setting one of them to 0.

Comment: Can you please explain the conditions with M? How do they make sure that f Si <= 0 then Si1 must equal 0, and if Si >= 0 then Si2 must equal 0.
Say Si=10. We want Si1=10 and Si2=0.
So the first condition brings 9M<=10? That cant happen.

Comment: If `Si < 0` then the LHS of the first constraint must also be `< 0`; setting `Si1 = 1` would make it `=0`, so we must set `Si1 = 0`, which makes the constraint satisfied trivially. Similarly for the other constraint. My solution used `<=` and `>=` but they should be strict inequalities, I will edit.

Comment: Si is a real number, and so should the Si1 abd Si2 be. Not binary?

Comment: Ack. sorry. I am not concentrating enough. I will edit.